# Case-Sensitive Jquery getQuery URL Param

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping this is a quick answer for someone. I have built a form that is passing a few query params to the end of the URL and I'm using Jquery to get the param values based on the param names. My JQuery code seems to be case-sensitive which is causing some issues. For example, my param name is 'Blah' and my Jquery code is looking for 'blah', and it it won't work. Is there an easy way to update this code to be case-insensitive so that I don't have to manually account for all possible cases (e.g. blah, Blah, BLAH, blAh, blaH, etc.)?

Sample Jquery Code:

```
(function ($) {
        $.getQuery = function (query) {
            query = query.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var expr = "[\\?&]" + query + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(expr);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (results !== null) {
                return results[1];
                return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
    var lang = $.getQuery('blah');
```

I also have similar code that I'm using in JavaScript that is case-sensitive too. Is there an easy way to change this code to be case-insensitive as well?

```
      var dURL = document.URL;
       function getParams() { //Get Name and (=) Values out of URL string after each &
           var idx = dURL.indexOf('?');
           var pnd = dURL.indexOf('#');
           var fparams = new Array();
           if (idx > -1) {
               if (pnd > idx) {
                   var pairs = dURL.substring(idx + 1, (pnd - idx)).split('&');
               } else {
                   var pairs = dURL.substring(idx + 1, document.URL.length).split('&');
               }
               for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                   nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                   fparams[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
               }
           }
           return fparams;
       }

       var params = getParams();

       if (params["blah"] != window.undefined) {
           lang = unescape(params["blah"]);
       } else {
           blah= '';
       }
```

Any information that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using js toLower should work

```
(function ($) {
    $.getQuery = function (query) {
        query = query.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var expr = "[\\?&]" + query + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(expr);
        var results = regex.exec(window.location.href.toLower());
        if (results !== null) {
            return results[1];
            return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```